# Is there a way to let a JSP file be served with the HTML extension in AEM?

Tags: aem, sling

I have a page that contains dynamic content:

```
/content/foo/bar/baz.jsp
```

But I want it to be accessible with the `.html` extension.

What's proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing some concepts in Apache Sling.

On Sling you have two important directories **/apps** and **/content**. In /apps you should put all your JSPs, in /content, as the name suggest, you only put content. Content being resources and their properties.

Nodes in /content have a property `sling:resourceType`. When a node from /content is requested, Sling looks for the resourceType of that node and invokes a JSP in the matching directory under /apps (and /libs if not found).

So, you must put your JSP under /apps/yourapp/foo/bar/bar.jsp (or with the file named 'bar.html.jsp', if you want to be explicit).

Then create a node /content/page with a prop `sling:resourceType="yourapp/foo/bar"`. When requesting /content/page.html, bar.jsp will be invoked.

The process that Sling chooses to select which JSP invoke at each request is a bit complicated at first, but it follows simple conventions regarding the name of the JSP. Check their documentation regarding [URL to script resolution](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/url-to-script-resolution.html).

Check the [Discover Sling in 15 minutes tutorial](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/getting-started/discover-sling-in-15-minutes.html) and the rest of their docs. They are pretty simple.

Comment: Note that /apps and /content are not fixed in any way, but it's correct that by default Sling looks for rendering scripts under /apps and /libs. Setting a sling:resourceType property on a node under /apps will also work (but let's not confuse things ;-) The key concept here is that as opposed to other Web frameworks Sling doesn't serve scripts, it serves content resources that are rendered via scripts or servlets.